# Convert long long into Hex and Binary in c++

Tags: c++, binary, hex, long-integer

I have this code:

```
char digits[] = { '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'A', 'B',
    'C', 'D', 'E', 'F' };
string toFormatFromDecimal(long long t, Format format) {
    int digitCount = ceil(log(t) / log((int) format));
    string hex = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < digitCount; i++) {
        hex += digits[(int) (t%format)];
        t = t/format;
    }        
    return string(hex.rbegin(), hex.rend());
}
string toHexFromDecimal(long long t) {
        return "0x" + toFormatFromDecimal(t, HEX);
}

string toBinFromDecimal(long long t) {
    return toFormatFromDecimal(t, BIN);
}
```

This should convert long long into hex- or binary-representation, which works well for all possitive numbers, but doesn't with negative numbers.

Any ideas how I can extend my code to handle signed numbers as well?
Thanks Florian

EDIT: Now I have a similar problem for the opposite (String -> long long) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19010032/convert-hex-bin-or-decimal-string-to-long-long-in-c)

Comment: That depends: Do you want -16 (decimal) to be -10(hexadecimal) or the hardware-internal, two's complement notation?

Comment: the two's complement.

Comment: I bet it does not work for zero either :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To convert the signed values, just convert your input to
`unsigned long long`.  Other than that: you don't need to
establish a digit count, once you're dealing with an unsigned
integral type, just continue until it is `0`.  And to make sure
you get at least one digit, even if the original value was `0`,
use a `do ... while` loop:

```
std::string results;
unsigned long long tmp = t;
do
{
    results += digits[ tmp % format ];
    tmp /= format;
} while ( tmp != 0 );
std::reverse( results.begin(), results.end() );
return results;
```

An often better solution is to pass the minimum number of digits
in as an argument:

```
std::string
toString( unsigned long long value, int base, int minSize = 1 )
{
    static char const digits[] = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    assert( base >= 2 && base <= 36 );
    std::string results;
    while ( value != 0 || results.size() < minSize ) {
        results += digits[ value % base ];
        value /= base;
    }
    std::reverse( results.begin(), results.end() );
    return results;
}
```

This allows fixed format, if desired.

Comment: thanks. the conversion to unsigned long long solved my problem!

Answer (score 2):

You do not need to count digits upfront: it's costly, and it does not work for negative numbers.

Since you specified that you would like to see a two's complement representation, use `unsigned long long` for your `t` to avoid negatives.

Change your loop to continue dividing by `format` until the number gets to zero, like this:

```
string toFormatFromDecimal(unsigned long long t, Format format) {
    string res = "";
    do {
        res += digits[(int) (t%format)];
        t = t/format;
    } while (t);
    return string(res.rbegin(), res.rend());
}
```

Comment: The conversion is not what I'm looking for but thanks for showing me how to optimize my code!

Comment: I don't think that's what he wanted for the negatives.  (At least according to his comment.)  And if it was, you're version has undefined behavior (and won't work) on most machines if `t` is `LLINT_MIN`.

Comment: And of course, there's no reason to special case `0`.  Just use a `do...while` loop.

Comment: @JamesKanze I missed OP's comment - I guess I was busy typing up the answer. Also thanks for the suggestion to convert the loop to do-while - it's a lot shorter this way.

Answer (score 1):

If your number is negative you must do:

```
myNumber = Long.MAXVALUE + myNumber + 1;
```

After that set the `most significant bit`.

An example: Assuming, your Long does not have 64 bit but only 4.

```
You have the number -3 (1101)
number = 7 + (-3) + 1 = 5 (0101)
```

So now you have the complement positive number. If you now set the most significant bit you have your negative number again:

```
("1"101) = -1
```

So what I mean is, you could calculate the **positive complement** of your number that you could describe like you did and now you just have to make sure, that your most significant hex is a number with the first significant bit set.So you have to add 8 to the most significant hex.

E.g. you calculate `4FFA` for your **positive complement** number you just have to change it to `CFFA`, because `C = 4 + 8`.

Comment: Thank you. I'm nearly there!
My result is now AE84B0F3B9CE01 then I have to padd zeros 00AE84B0F3B9CE01 and add 8 as you mentioned which leads me to the final result of 80AE84B0F3B9CE01 which is what I want! But how can I add this 8 to get the right result in any case? No matter if it's a 2 byte or a 16 byte value?

Comment: Just converting to `unsigned long long` takes care of everything directly, without any tests nor additional work.  And on most machines, it doesn't generate any code.

Comment: So one hex number is always 4 bit so one byte which means its 2^(number of bits - 1)

Answer (score 0):

For the hexadecimal variant, how about just use `std::istringstream` and normal stream formatting?

Like

```
std::string toHexFromDecimal(long long t) {
    std::istringstream is;
    is << std::hex << t;
    return t.str();
}
```

For binary, how about something like this:

```
std::string toBinFromDecimal(long long t) {
    std::string s;

    for (int bit = sizeof(t) * 8 - 1; bit >= 0; --bit) {
        s += '0' + (t >> bit) & 1;
    }

    return s;
}
```

Comment: Note that the two solutions you propose give radically different
results (not just the base) for negative numbers.  They also
handle fill differently.